# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError when request a simple url

Tags: python, python-requests

I think the following step is self-explained,it's simple.

But why `Python requests` will be crashed on this case.

It seems the redirect may be the reason ?

However  I can visit the page with chrome/firefox correctly,

How could I get my result ? thanks

```
(Pdb) requests.get(req_url)
*** requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
(Pdb) req_url
'https://book.flypeach.com/default.aspx?chd=0&dep=2015-11-25&adt=1&des=OKA&langculture=zh-TW&ori=TPE&ao=B2CZHTW&bLFF=false&inf=0'
```

Comment: What I get here is "requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'book.flypeach.com' doesn't match either of '*.avantik.io', 'avantik.io'"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i'm using python3 requests

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to behave more like Firefox.
You analyze the way Firefox talks to the web page
and then send the same headers. Accepting cookies
is also useful.

The following python 2.7.10 code successfully reads the page:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar

MyURL = 'https://book.flypeach.com/default.aspx?chd=0&dep=2015-11-25&adt=1&des=OKA&langculture=zh-TW&ori=TPE&ao=B2CZHTW&bLFF=false&inf=0'
cj = CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders=[ ('User-Agent', r'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0'),
                          ('Accept', r'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,text/vnd.wap.wml;q=0.6'),
                          ('Accept-Language', 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'),
                          ('Accept-Encoding', 'deflate'),
                          ('DNT', '1'),
                          ('Referer', r'https://book.flypeach.com'),
                          ('Host', 'book.flypeach.com'),
                          ('Cache-Control', r'max-age=0'),
                          ('Connection', r'keep-alive')
                        ] 

response = opener.open(MyURL)
html_result = response.read()
print html_result
```

Comment: @newBike the key point is to behave like a normal web browser. These send the browser type in the headers and usually accept cookies. Once you got the script working, you can throw out the cookiejar if your target web site does not require it. For Firefox there's a plugin called Firebug, This will show you the browser communication and also any cookies sent or received. With this info it's usually easy to automate the same request.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the bug is due to openssl problem,

it seems i didn't install python 3.4.3 with the correctly openssl version.

so i decide to install new python version 3.5.0 and with correct openssl path.

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \\
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \\
pyenv install 3.5.0
```

and the simply  added the flag  `verify=False`

```
resp = s.get(req_url, headers=self.headers, verify=False)
```

everything works fine now.